Select object from first table, who doesn`t have true in second
I have table with objects



uuid
name




98665e5a-e1cb-4bf7-93fa-a8d13983f358
object



and another table with information about enabled this object and another object together



uuid_from_table_upper
enabled
uuid_another_object




98665e5a-e1cb-4bf7-93fa-a8d13983f358
true
ad5e670a-adac-485b-879e-9448d68a393c


98665e5a-e1cb-4bf7-93fa-a8d13983f358
false
a55b021b-ae4b-4373-91ae-87b9f7134862



i need a sql query, return object from first table object, who doesn`t have true in second table
SELECT ft.* 
FROM first_table ft 
  JOIN second_table st on ft.uuid = st.uuid_from_table_upper
WHERE
  not st.enabled;

i guess needed group by or recursive with

What would be the desired result? What is the meaning of the UUID columns in the second table?

disired result is null, cause uuid from first table have a true in relations table, UUID columns in the second table is relations

That is not explanation enough for me to understand. Perhaps somebody else can.

SELECT *
FROM first_table 
WHERE NOT EXIST (
    SELECT NULL
    FROM second_table 
    WHERE first_table.uuid = second_table.uuid_from_table_upper
      AND second_table.enabled
    );


If you want to do this with joins, you might have to cater for two cases:

table2 contains a row with enabled = false, or
table2 does not contain a matching row at all.

This should cater for both cases:
select t1.*, t2.* 
from first_table t1 
inner join second_table t2 
      on t1.uuid = t2.uuid_from_table_upper
where t2.enabled = false 
UNION ALL 
select t1.*, t2.* 
from first_table t1 
left join second_table t2 
     on t1.uuid = t2.uuid_from_table_upper
where t2.uuid_from_table_upper IS NULL 
ORDER BY ... 
;


SELECT first_table.*
FROM first_table
LEFT JOIN second_table on first_table.uuid = second_table.uuid_from_table_upper and not(second_table.enabled)
WHERE second_table.uuid_from_table_upper is null;

